# What is the correct translation for a "BACK" button?

Tags: mobile, back-button

I am fluent in Spanish,
but this one has me struggling for some reason. What would be the correct translation for a **"BACK"** button in Spanish? If you want want to go **back** to the previous screen. Should it be regreso, anterior?

Comment: I could write an answer but I think this question belongs to [spanish.stackexchange](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Try checking your browser's Help/ user documentation in Spanish and see what word they use.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to translate "Back" in this context. A lot depends on your target audience since this can change depending on the country. I like "Volver," "Retroceder," and "Atras." Any of these options would work. One way to localize your translation (you probably already know this) is to search for sites in your target country ("website topic" + site:.mx (for Mexico) or site:.es (for Spain) and so on, and see what terms they use. Having said that, just using the arrow icon and adding a tooltip that explains what the "botón de retroceso" may be enough.